# Copying Rows from Different Sheets with Varying Row Numbers to a Single Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro to copy rows starting from A7 from different sheets to a "Data" sheet. The Rows in each sheet vary. It is just copying Row 7 in each sheet. Here's my code:

```
 Sub Button1_Click()

 Worksheets("Data").Cells.ClearContents

 Dim x As Integer
 Dim y As Integer
 Dim ws1 As Worksheet
 Dim First As Integer
 Dim Last As Integer
 Dim i As Integer

     Set ws1 = Worksheets("Data")
     First = Worksheets("Data").Index
     Last = Worksheets("Summary").Index

     ws1.Range("A" & 1).Value = "Date"
     ws1.Range("B" & 1).Value = "Equipment"
     ws1.Range("C" & 1).Value = "Type"
     ws1.Range("D" & 1).Value = "Qty / Hrs"
     ws1.Range("E" & 1).Value = "Rate"
     ws1.Range("F" & 1).Value = "Cost"

      For i = (First + 1) To (Last - 1)

      With Sheets(i)

          MaxrOw = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
          x = 7

          Do Until .Range("A" & x).Value = ""
          If Not .Range("I" & x).Value = "" Then

              ws1.Range("A" & MaxrOw + 1).Value = .Range("G" & 2).Value
              ws1.Range("B" & MaxrOw + 1).Value = .Range("A" & x).Value
              ws1.Range("C" & MaxrOw + 1).Value = .Range("B" & x).Value
              ws1.Range("D" & MaxrOw + 1).Value = .Range("G" & x).Value
              ws1.Range("E" & MaxrOw + 1).Value = .Range("H" & x).Value
              ws1.Range("F" & MaxrOw + 1).Value = .Range("I" & x).Value

              x = x + 1
          Else
              x = x + 1

          End If

      Loop

      End With

      Next i

      Columns("A:F").Sort key1:=Range("C1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

 End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: MaxrOw is in the wrong place.  and it does not qualify the parent. Move this line just below the `Do Until` line: `MaxrOw = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Row`.  And remove the one you have.

Comment: Thank you.  It is working now.

Comment: I am pleased that Scott's comment allowed to get this code working but this is still very inefficient code. I would like to suggest something better but first I have a question. You copy column G twice; was one of them meant to be column C?

Comment: Hi Tony, G2 is where the date is. I have to copy the date in each row. Gx below where the other data are.

Answer (score 0):

Scott Craner has fixed your syntactical issue, but, as others have mentioned, there are some inefficiencies in your code. Have a look here as a starting point https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff726673(v=office.14).aspx.

So, for your code:

1. The loop through worksheet indexes can't be relied upon. For example, if you moved the "Data" or "Summary" sheet (deliberately or by mistake), you'd risk missing some sheets out of the loop. It's more reliable to loop through the `Worksheets` collection and testing if each is a worksheet you want, say by its name.
2. Whenever you're reading to and from the worksheet, it's usually quicker to read and write to/from a variant array. Writing cell by cell, in particular, is notoriously time-consuming.
3. Finding the last row is also unnecessary for each row iteration. Quicker would be to find it once and then simply add 1 each time you write a line. Of course, quicker still would be point #2.

The code below resolves these three issues. It's not the most memory efficient but it will be quick.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim dataSets As Collection
Dim output() As Variant
Dim dataValues(1) As Variant
Dim d As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim v As Variant

'Acquire the data from each sheet and aggregate the output array size
Set dataSets = New Collection
d = 2
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Data" And ws.Name <> "Summary" Then
        dataValues(0) = ws.Range("G2").Value
        dataValues(1) = ws.Range("A7", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Resize(, 9).Value2
        d = d + UBound(dataValues(1), 1)
        dataSets.Add dataValues
    End If
Next

'Redimension the output array
ReDim output(1 To d, 1 To 6)

'Populate the header
output(1, 1) = "Date"
output(1, 2) = "Equipment"
output(1, 3) = "Type"
output(1, 4) = "Qty / Hrs"
output(1, 5) = "Rate"
output(1, 6) = "Cost"

'Populate the output array with values
d = 2
For Each v In dataSets
    For x = 1 To UBound(v(1), 1)
        output(d, 1) = v(0)
        output(d, 2) = v(1)(x, 1)
        output(d, 3) = v(1)(x, 2)
        output(d, 4) = v(1)(x, 7)
        output(d, 5) = v(1)(x, 8)
        output(d, 6) = v(1)(x, 9)
        d = d + 1
    Next
Next

'Write the array
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(output, 1), UBound(output, 2)).Value = output
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try to use this code. I am not really familiar with VBA. This is the first code I've written.